# Xamarin socket.io connect on button press

Tags: c#, xamarin, socket.io

I started using xamarin yesterday so I am quite new to both C# and how it works yet. Have been using Socket.io for a while in other projects tho. 
What I am trying to do right now is connect to the server the user inputs in a TextEdit. Take that URL and connect on click, and it works fine it connects. The problem is that it just keeps on connecting and creating more and more sockets all connected to the server at the same time. If I add manualresetevent.waitOne(5000); it will only create one socket. But this is kind of inconvenient. 
This will just continue to create sockets and not stop. PS: Only happens on button click not if I put the connection in the OnCreate.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private ManualResetEvent ManualResetEvent = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        var count = 0;

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Button testConnection = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.test);
        EditText serverURL = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.serverURL);
        TextView view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.debug);
        testConnection.Click += delegate
        {
            count++;
            socket = IO.Socket(serverURL.Text);
            view.Text = count.ToString();
            socket.On("connect", () =>
            {

            });
            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, () =>
            {

            });  
        };
    }
}
```

And My other version which only creates two sockets. The difference being the socket.Connect()

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private ManualResetEvent ManualResetEvent = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        var count = 0;

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Button testConnection = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.test);
        EditText serverURL = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.serverURL);
        TextView view = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.debug);
        testConnection.Click += delegate
        {
            count++;
            socket = IO.Socket(serverURL.Text);
            socket.Connect();
            view.Text = count.ToString();
            socket.On("connect", () =>
            {

            });
            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, () =>
            {

            });  
        };
    }
}
```

I am using this component https://components.xamarin.com/view/socketioclientdotnet

Comment: That's the thing. The click counter only increments once.

Comment: The toasts do not work, but the code for the toast runs multiple times in the debugger.

Comment: Also if I run socket.Connect() afterwords it stops the previous IO.Socket() and connects a last time.
So if I run 
socket = IO.Socket();
it will only connect twice
socket.Connect()

Comment: Don't know what you did not understand so will try and formulate myself differently this time :) 
At the moment my connection code is and it runs indefinitely 
socket = IO.Socket(location)

but if I add I get one connection for IO.Socket and one for socket.connect() and that is it. So I only end up with 2 sockets. 

socket = IO.Socket(location)
socket.connect()

Comment: Yep, the code is missing parts I guess.

Comment: Please update the question. I will clean some comments i made (this is getting to big) and then we talk again.

Comment: I have updated the question. With all I have written so far. I left out the using, and added another snippet with the "socket.Connect()"