# Xamarin Socket.IO Client keeps creating multiple sockets

Tags: .net, xamarin, socket.io, client

I've been working with Xamarin-Android and am trying to create a Socket.IO client that communicates with my Socket.IO server in Node.js on a button press. I am using this Socket.IO Client Library for .Net https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet.

However, when I run the below code, instead of opening one socket, it keeps creating more and more sockets and connects to the server ("incoming connection" in the server code keeps getting written to the console continuously). When I run the same code as Windows Blank Project, it seems to work fine, only a single socket is being created. This has been already addressed in the past here [Xamarin socket.io connect on button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906668/xamarin-socket-io-connect-on-button-press) but there doesn't seem to be any solution in that thread. I've been trying to get this working for a long time now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Changed the URL from localhost to actual server's URL and added Node.JS Server code for clarity

EDIT 2: Node JS server is running on VM with Bridged Adapter (so it has a unique IP address of it's own and doesn't share the host's IP). The emulator is running on the host machine. I think that the NodeJS server is trying to respond to the Emulator's request but the response is actually sent to the host machine and thus the Emulator keeps retrying to connect to the Server. So I believe I need to set up some kind of forwarding from the host machine to the Emulator. Any help or guidance regarding this would be great. Thank you!

Socet.IO client code

```
button.Click += delegate {
    var socket = IO.Socket("http://193.61.190.46:9000/ingestintoDB");
    socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
    {
        socket.Emit("hello", "new connection");
    });
}
```

Node.JS server code

```
var ingestintoDB = io.of('/ingestintoDB');
ingestintoDB.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log("incoming connection");
   socket.on('hi', function(data){
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the device/emulator itself since you are using `localhost` (127.0.0.1), it ended up failing and thus the Socket.IO client is repeating the connect over and over as you are not handling the failure condition of the connect.

Change your connection to use the IP address (or hostname if DNS resolvable) of your node.js server (assuming you are self-hosting).

i.e.

```
http://192.168.1.2:9000/ingestintoDB
```

You can also use the auto-assigned loopback address of your PC that your emulator can reach, depending upon the emulator that you are using:

```
http://10.0.2.2:9000/ingestintoDB
```

Or

```
http://10.0.3.2:9000/ingestintoDB
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I edited my post to change it to the IP address of NodeJS server. I can see the new incoming connections in the console of my NodeJS server and the number of connections keep on increasing

Comment: Hi Sushi, I think I figured out what the issue is. I edited my post for better clarification. Any help regarding this would be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Corleone You can use Android's `adb` to a forward port  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#forwardports Adb can also do port reversing (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/SERVICES.TXT search for "adb reverse"). If you are using Bridge networking on your VM, as long as it is on the same subnet as your PC your can forward the ports just fine...

Comment: @Corleone It is easier at times just to add another NIC on the VM, assign it an IP address on the emulator's subnet and bind Node.JS to that address. Then no port forwarding/reversing as the emulator and server as on the same network segment and no network subnet hopping is required....